# Simple ajax call in wordpress for upvoting post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Here's my ajax call:

```
$("#yes, #no").click(function(){
    var upOrDown = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        action: "updateVote",
        data: {upOrDown: upOrDown},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data.output);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Here's the function in functions.php

```
function updateVote() {
    echo json_encode(array(
        'output' => 'hello!'
    ));
    die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_updateVote', 'updateVote');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_updateVote', 'updateVote');
```

Why does this keep returning "0". It should return "hello!"

Thanks.

Comment: What's the structure like if you only do `console.log(data)`

Comment: @Spokey i get 0 as well

Comment: Not sure...Put `exit;` after `echo` statement.

Comment: @Gowri nope still getting the same result

Comment: Just Check what you actually getting response `console.log(data);`

Comment: @Gowri Just needed to add the action as part of the data: parameter, and it worked. thanks.